# Why is ctrlKey's behaviour so weird?

Tags: javascript, electron, keyevent

Example snippet:

```js
document.addEventListener('keydown', (event) => {
    if (event.code === 'Delete') {
        console.log('The delete key was pressed' + 
        (event.ctrlKey ? ' while the control key was held down.' : '.'));
    }
});
```

In this example, the second snippet seems to never be applied. If I change `event.ctrlKey` to `event.altKey`, and press `alt`+`del`, it logs properly like I expect it to.

Can someone help me understand this inconsistent behaviour, and help me find a fix?

EDIT: Something I should have mentioned - it seems to be working fine in a browser (Chrome). The applied scenario is actually an Electron based application. I've also noticed it's not not-logging the second snippet - the keyEvent isn't firing at all. This is now leading me to think it's a clashing keybind, or the application is preventing the key. I'd still like to know if there's a (proper) workaround to this though.

Comment: Your code is working as expected for me.  Dump it in a console then click on your page (document) and all it works fine.  Maybe it's a browser thing?

Comment: The support table of `event.code` seems [quite red](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent/code#Browser_compatibility)

Comment: @jmargolisvt Interesting, I hadn't actually tested in Chrome - it's actually applied in a Chromium-based application (Discord). Looks like it's something specific to that client then. I also noticed it's not not-logging the second snippet - it isn't logging anything at all. The keyEvent never fires. This leads me to think it might be a clashing keybind?

Answer (score 0):

You're probably on a Mac? Than `|| event.metaKey` could help

```
document.addEventListener('keydown', (event) => {
    if (event.code === 'Delete') {
        console.log('The delete key was pressed' + 
        ((event.ctrlKey || event.metaKey) ? ' while the control key was held down.' : '.'));
    }
});
```

Comment: I'm not - take a look at my edit, I believe it's not a specific issue with <keyEvent>.ctrlKey but rather the application I'm working in.

Comment: @aetheryx hummm instead of `(event) => {` have you tried to use `function (event) {`

Comment: Same result. The key combo `Delete` + `ctrl` seems to be occupied, it's not logging anything. Happen to know any way I could "override" that?